# With Media Queries, have div hidden until screen size is small enough?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a navbar set up and as the screen size gets smaller my navbar sections get closer together until eventually i have them display:none. at this point i have a button for a dropdown menu that takes the place of my navbar links but I CANT FIGURE OUT HOW TO MAKE IT SHOW UP ONLY ON SCREEN SIZES WITH MAX-WIDTH 600px or less. It is either visible along side my navbar links and after they are hidden, or not visible at all. HELP.

here is my media query for this section

```
    @media (max-width:600px) {
    #main-pic{margin: 0 0 0 -220px;}
    #welcomesign{margin: 0 0 0 -40px;}
    #navprojects{display:none;}
    #navcontact{display:none}
    #navartwork{display:none}
    #navresume{display:none;}
    #navhome{display:none;}
    #3bd{visibility:visible}
    }
```

and here is the html

```
    <ul>    
      <a id="nav1" class="eight" href=index.html><img id="sgmainlogo"                         src="sgproject4.png" alt=SGproject style=55px;width:55px;position:absolute;left:10px;top:4px;></a>
     <li id="navhome"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=home.html>Home</a></li>
     <li id="navresume"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=resume.html>Resume</a></li>
     <li id="navprojects"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=projects.html>Projects</a></li>
     <li id="navartwork"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=artwork.html>Artwork</a></li>
     <li id="navcontact"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=contact.html>Contact</a></li>

     <div id="3bd" class="dropdown" style="visibility:hidden;">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn fa fa-bars"></button>
       <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="six" href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a class="six" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        <a class="six" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        <a class="six" href="artwork.html">Artwork</a>
        <a class="six" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `div` inside `ul` wiyhout a wrapping `li` is invalid html, maybe start there. same applies for that first `a`

Comment: To continue: the `style` of the image needs to wrapped in `"`

Comment: IDs have to be unique in the document

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comments: The only valid child of `ul` is an `li` element. So your `a` and `div` are invalid html here.

You should always wrap your inline attributes in quotation marks `"` 
In addition to that, IDs have to be unique throughout the document, you are using `#nav` multiple times.

The issue why your media query is not working could be your ID `3bd` starting with a digit. This is only alowed when using a HTML5 doctype and **the inline style overriding your css style**

Try this instead:
I fixed the html issues and extracted the inline style to the css outside the media query.

```css
#id_3bd {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  #main-pic {
    margin: 0 0 0 -220px;
  }
  #welcomesign {
    margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
  }
  #navprojects {
    display: none;
  }
  #navcontact {
    display: none;
  }
  #navartwork {
    display: none;
  }
  #navresume {
    display: none;
  }
  #navhome {
    display: none;
  }
  #id_3bd {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="nav1" class="eight" href="index.html"><img id="sgmainlogo" src="sgproject4.png" alt="SGproject" style="height:55px;width:55px;position:absolute;left:10px;top:4px;"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="navhome"><a id="nav2" class="ten" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li id="navresume"><a id="nav3" class="ten" href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
  <li id="navprojects"><a id="nav4" class="ten" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
  <li id="navartwork"><a id="nav5" class="ten" href="artwork.html">Artwork</a></li>
  <li id="navcontact"><a id="nav6" class="ten" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li>
    <div id="id_3bd" class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn fa fa-bars"></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="six" href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a class="six" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        <a class="six" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        <a class="six" href="artwork.html">Artwork</a>
        <a class="six" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline css in which you are applying media query and put the media query below your default css.

```css
.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  #main-pic {
    margin: 0 0 0 -220px;
  }
  #welcomesign {
    margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
  }
  #navprojects {
    display: none;
  }
  #navcontact {
    display: none
  }
  #navartwork {
    display: none
  }
  #navresume {
    display: none;
  }
  #navhome {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown {
    visibility: visible
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a id="nav1" class="eight" href=index.html><img id="sgmainlogo" src="sgproject4.png" alt=SGproject style=55px;width:55px;position:absolute;left:10px;top:4px;></a>
  <li id="navhome"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=home.html>Home</a></li>
  <li id="navresume"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=resume.html>Resume</a></li>
  <li id="navprojects"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=projects.html>Projects</a></li>
  <li id="navartwork"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=artwork.html>Artwork</a></li>
  <li id="navcontact"><a id="nav" class="ten" href=contact.html>Contact</a></li>

  <div id="3bd" class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn fa fa-bars"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="six" href="home.html">Home</a>
      <a class="six" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
      <a class="six" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
      <a class="six" href="artwork.html">Artwork</a>
      <a class="six" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know the html is invalid if we use div inside ul or li tags, but I was just answering him about media query, it should be in the below of default css.